# understanding GC failure message

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

I see this in my GC log but what does it really means and how can I solve it (using CMS)

```
[GC (Allocation Failure) 2018-01-08T12:09:08.677+0000: 45.380: [ParNew
Desired survivor size 8945664 bytes, new threshold 6 (max 6)
- age   1:    4558248 bytes,    4558248 total
- age   2:     246416 bytes,    4804664 total
- age   3:    1575864 bytes,    6380528 total
: 142273K->6418K(157248K), 0.0235404 secs] 234438K->98584K(506816K), 0.0237255 secs] [Times: user=0.03 sys=0.00, real=0.03 secs]
```

Comment: is the program not working?

Comment: Solve what exactly? The question is unclear. Are you asking how to solve 'GC (Allocation Failure)' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a. Allocation Failure : It simply means that the program asked for memory and there was none available. Thus, a minor GC was exeucted to free up the memory for new object to be created. If an application has too many allocation failure, increasing the size of Young Gen/Eden space is the way to go.
Please refer the following link, that is great for tips on tuning the JVM.
https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27013824&aid=1

Answer (score 1):

This (Allocation Failure) just means that a GC was triggered because there was not enough memory to do an allocation. There is no problem to solve here.